# Django does not update with UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I have this view to show the previously populated data, which was only populated in the admin panel:

```
from .models import (Token,
                     Sell,
                     LogisticCost,
                     IncomeCost,
                     FinalPayment,
                     CustomerServiceCost,
                     Fatura)
def product_list(request):
    context = {'product_list': ProductList.objects.filter(client=request.user.id).all(),
               'data_payment': Fatura.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'Clientes/list_products.html', context)
```

This is the view to update these values:

```
class UpdateProduct(UpdateView):
    model = ProductList
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'Clientes/update_product.html'
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'cost_price', 'sell_price', 'ncm']
```

My form in the update page is:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'client:product_list' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
</form>
```

My update page is working as expected, showing every value related to the selected object, but when I submit the form the model has not changed. What is happening to not update the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting the form to the `product_list` view - you should submit it to the update view instead.

Depending on your URLs, the form should look something like:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'client:update_product' product_list.pk %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, I removed the action from the form and I added the variable `success_url = reverse_lazy('client:product_list')` to my UpdateView. That solved the problem.